# How to do this same analysis with MapReduce and Aggregate

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mapreduce, aggregation-framework

i need to make this analysis using mapReduce and/or aggregate:

```
DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("documents");
DBCursor cursor = coll.find();
Map<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
while(cursor.hasNext()){
    DBObject obj = cursor.next();
    BasicDBList list = (BasicDBList)obj.get("cats");
    for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
        String cat = list.get(i).toString();
        int hits   = 0;
        if(map.containsKey(cat)){
            hits = map.get(cat);
        }
        hits++;
        map.put(cat, hits);
    }
}
```

Can someone give me a right example on how to use mapReduce AND aggregate to achive what i need?

Thanks!

Comment: It might help to add a sample document and generally an expected result rather than make people guess at the structure.

Comment: Reading [How To Ask Questions The Smart way](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) will surely boost the number of answers, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be counting unique occurrences of elements in an array. Whatever the content it does not matter as you are just casting to a string key in your map. But here's a sample:

```js
{ "cats" : [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ] }
{ "cats" : [ 2, 4 ] }
{ "cats" : [ 1, 5 ] }
{ "cats" : [ 4, 5 ] }
```

The aggregation framework is the fastest:

```js
db.cats.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$cats" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$cats",
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }}
])
```

Which produces:

```js
{ "_id" : 5, "count" : 3 }
{ "_id" : 4, "count" : 3 }
{ "_id" : 3, "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 2, "count" : 2 }
{ "_id" : 1, "count" : 2 }
```

Map reduce is much the same but slower:

```js
db.cats.mapreduce(
    function() {
        this.cats.forEach(function(cat) {
            emit( cat, 1 );
        });
    },
    function(key,values) {
        return Array.sum( values );
    },
    { "out": { "inline": 1 } }
)
```

Comment: Thank you! That's what i need! Using one million of document with 20 cats each, the time spent to do the aggregation is about 5 seconds. Is there a way to fastify much?

Comment: @JackTurky Sharding would be your best option from here. There are ways to process arrays inline in latest versions of MongoDB but not for "counting the distinct values". Memory and distribution are generally the key. But again, in latest versions.